# Reading file .xlsx from desktop(my PC) which is already present there with same extension. #JupyterLab web-based interactive development environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Code:

```
import xlrd
    loc = input(r'Enter the path of your file: ')
    print(loc)
    #loc="C:\Users\anuj.masand\Desktop\PrototypeIncidentAudit.xlsx"
    assert os.path.exists(loc), "I did not find the file at, "+str(loc)

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
    Print("I got it")
```

Error:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4ab769c51fe8> in <module>
      3 print(loc)
      4 #loc="C:\Users\anuj.masand\Desktop\PrototypeIncidentAudit.xlsx"
----> 5 assert os.path.exists(loc), "I did not find the file at, "+str(loc)
      6 
      7 wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)

AssertionError: I did not find the file at, C:\Users\anuj.masand\Desktop\PrototypeIncidentAudit.xlsx
```

> Why am I getting this error if it's already there on my desktop?

Comment: import os is also not working.

Comment: Working fine on pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import xlrd
import os

loc = input(r'Enter the path of your file: ')
print(loc)

if os.path.isfile(loc):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
    print("I got it")
else:
    print(f"I did not find the file at {loc}.")
```

Comment: This just another way but the problem still persist as to why jupyterlab is unable to read file which can be read with same code anywhere else?

Comment: if you populate the loc variable with quoted string ("") the code will fail. Just enter the full path without the quotes. Tested right now.

Comment: #ToCarbajal I have found my answer. ("") are no issues. I am using the Jupyter notebook on my browser, online. Now I have figured it out,  Firstly I ran print(os. getcwd()) that gave me an idea where am I right now then explored a bit and found out that i can simply upload my file on to the binder by opening dashboard i. e. File>Open. I have uploaded my document there and now its working fine with path change ofcourse(/home/jovyan/binder/PrototypeIncidentAudit.xlsx')

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Since I am working on an online **web-based interactive development environment**, all I was required to do is to upload the document on to the dashboard(`/home/jovyan/binder/`) by simply going to the menu bar, File>Open.

> I have uploaded my document there and now its working fine with path
>   change ofcourse(`/home/jovyan/binder/PrototypeIncidentAudit.xlsx'`)